# SELECT with COUNT from multiple tables in access 2007

Tags: sql, select, count, ms-access-2007

I have 2 queries called "3 Month Query" and "6 Month Query". Now I'm creating a report with a query as a record source. I want to count the number of rows in 3 Month Query and label it as Need3Month, and the number of rows in 6 Month Query and label it as Need6Month. I tried the following which is not working:

```
SELECT COUNT([3 Month Query].[ID]) AS Need3Month, COUNT([6 Month Query].[ID]) AS Need6Month FROM [3 Month Query], [6 Month Query];
```

And I also tried:

```
SELECT COUNT([3 Month Query].[ID] AS Need3Month FROM [3 Month Query]
UNION
SELECT COUNT([6 Month Query].[ID] AS Need6Month FROM [6 Month Query];
```

This returns the right numbers but lists them both under a Need3Month column.

What am I supposed to do? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM [3 Month Query]) AS Need3Month,
  (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM [6 Month Query]) AS Need6Month
```

---

**UPDATE** in reply to comments:

```
SELECT
  COUNT([ID]) AS Need3Month,
  (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM [6 Month Query]) AS Need6Month
FROM [3 Month Query]
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

This should also work (I think):

```
SELECT
  Cnt6.Cnt AS Need3Month,
  Cnt3.Cnt AS Need3Month
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT([ID]) AS Cnt FROM [3 Month Query]) AS Cnt3,
  (SELECT COUNT([ID]) AS Cnt FROM [6 Month Query]) AS Cnt6
```

Comment: It says "Query input must contain as least one table or query". When I do the SELECT statement above and add to the end "FROM [3 Month Query], [6 Month Query]" it gives the right numbers but two rows for Need3Month and Need6Month where I only want one row...

Comment: Try including just one of the tables

Comment: I've voted this answer as I think you beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: @jrubins: Please have a look at the alternative solution.

Comment: That seems to bring me back to the original problem. It actually turns out that it's not an issue with the two rows cause it still works for what I need to do. Thanks so much

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry that actually works perfectly. I forgot I had just changed my data :-[. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it works in MS Access but in SQL you would do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [3 Month Query]) Need3Month, 
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [6 Month Query]) Need6Month
```

Comment: We both of us couldn't see each other's answers. So it's +1 from me too as honestly gained. :)